# Which property for "tags" informations

Tags: schema.org

I'm trying to add schema.org information on my site (that is an archive of authors and songs).
On my contents I've always a "tag" field (classical tags) and other information about "sections".

The question is: on Person type I've not a property for tags or something like this.
I've the same doubt for my fields "related links", related to an author or a song.

For "tags" and similat values (ways to "catalog" contents), may I use "category" property, even if is not a property for Person?

For "links" may I use "significantLinks", even if is not a property for Person or CreativeWork?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have code relating to this problem?

Comment: No no, on my cms (drupal) I've to set the "property" for every field. And I've the doubt about the property to set for my "tag" field and another field that "catalogs" content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must not use properties that are not defined for the type you use.

It’s correct that [Person](http://schema.org/Person) doesn’t offer a property that could be used for tags/categories, probably because it’s unusual to tag persons. There’s also no property that could be used for related links.

[CreativeWork](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) defines the properties [`about`](http://schema.org/about) ("The subject matter of the content.") and [`mentions`](http://schema.org/mentions) ("Indicates that the CreativeWork contains a reference to, but is not necessarily about a concept."). These could be used for tags.

[WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage), which is a more specific CreativeWork, also defines the property [`relatedLink`](http://schema.org/relatedLink) ("A link related to this web page, for example to other related web pages.").

So you might consider using WebPage (including related links and tags) with a Person child.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser.
What do you mean with "a Person child"? Could I use the property "additionalType" with "Person" value? I'm a newbie on schema.org :)

Comment: @sergiod: No, I guess `additionalType` doesn’t allow you to use the properties from `Person`. -- I meant, for example, `WebPage` on `<body>` and `Person` on a child element, e.g., `<article>`. To "connect" these, it would be best to use a property, but unfortunately, Schema.org doesn’t offer a suitable property for that (yet). Some may use the `about` property ([see example](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/61194/17633)), but this might not be 100% appropriate.